# get value from private field having object "Field". JAVA

Tags: java, hibernate, serialization, field

my problem is that, i want to save class object java.lang.reflect.Field into database using Hibernate.
E.g. table:

```
@Entity
public class Actor implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    private void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

and i have table for Conditions where i want to store java.lang.reflect.Field object via String:

```
@Entity
public class Conditions implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String value;
    private String field;
    private int type;

    public void setField(String field) {
        this.field = field;
    }

    public void setType(int type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getField() {
        return field;
    }

    public int getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    private void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

and now i would do something like that:

```
Conditions con;
// con = get our condition from database (via hibernate)
java.lang.reflect.Field f = Actor.class.getDeclaredField(con.getField());
Actor a = new Actor();
a.setName("My name");
String ActorName = f.get(a);
```

Here is my problem, now i got Exception like:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class testsms.TestSms can not access a member of class tables.Actor with modifiers "private"
```

Probably i need to use Actor.class.getDeclaredMethods() but i dont know how. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you try `f.setAccessible(true)` and then rerun your code ?